# How does my ObjC static class have two instances in memory?

Tags: objective-c, static, static-methods

I have a static class with two methods to set a static integer value. For some reason when calling it from different parts of my code, there seem to be two instances of the memory allocated.

The code:

**MyLogger.h**

```
@interface MyLogger : NSObject

+ (NSUInteger)loggingLevel;
+ (void)setLoggingLevel:(NSUInteger)loggingLevel;

@end
```

**MyLogger.m**

```
#import "MyLogger.h"

static NSUInteger myLoggingLevel = 0;

@implementation MyLogger

+ (NSUInteger)loggingLevel { 
    return myLoggingLevel; 
}

+ (void)setLoggingLevel:(NSUInteger)loggingLevel { 
    myLoggingLevel = loggingLevel;
}

@end
```

When I set and access that unsigned integer value from different parts of my code, it has different values and memory addresses.

Some example debugger output from breakpoint A:

```
(lldb) p myLoggingLevel
(NSUInteger) $1 = 32768
(lldb) p &myLoggingLevel
(NSUInteger *) $2 = 0x0000000110a57480
```

And from breakpoint B:

```
(lldb) p myLoggingLevel
(NSUInteger) $3 = 0
(lldb) p &myLoggingLevel
(NSUInteger *) $4 = 0x000000010f4733a8
```

Comment: where is A and B and from where do you access myLoggingLevel - do you dynamically link it in?

Comment: Interesting I'm assuming your breakpoint is set to `return myLoggingLevel`, does the address change every time you pass through the breakpoint or is it after certain calls?

Comment: I cant reproduce it.